# Drupal search according to language

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

In my website, we are using three different language by multilingual module.
but I want that in search bar if we search by English word then search content should be in English and if we search by marathi/hindi word then search content should be in that particular language.

How these will be possible in Drupal?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There is a special Drupal related Stack Exchange platform called Drupal Answers at drupal.stackexchange.com -- Regarding your question, Drupal search will automatically apply the language currently displayed, on Marathi version it will display Marathi results and vice versa.

Comment: no, I want that if the site is english and then we search by marathi word then it should marathi search content.

Comment: I do not know of any module that provides such functionality. Mainly, because how is Drupal supposed to know which language you entered? For example, the word "alter" could be English, German (old), Danish (altar) or even Latin (other). Of course, with only English and Marathi, it would easily be possible since they use different alphabets, but still I don't know of a way to achieve that through available modules.